# PHP. Undefined property: stdClass in a double query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

The second query does not work and Im trying to echo all in the information in the second query from another table but does appear the next message:
`Undefined property: stdClass::$titulo` (and the rest of "resultado2")
I tried to do a while like the first query (while ($nfila = $resultado2->fetch_object())) but does appear another error message:
`Trying to get property of non-object`

```
<?php
    $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario_valido'];
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM `lista-usuarios` WHERE categoria='favoritos' AND  nombreusuario='$usuario' ORDER BY pelicula ASC";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);

    if ($resultado)
        {
        $cont3 = 1; //Para el id de la peli
        $i = 0; //Para un class unico
        while ($nfila = $resultado->fetch_object())
            {
            $pelicula = "peli" . $cont3; //Para hacer un id unico de cada pelicula
            $i++;
            echo "<form role='form' id='$pelicula'><table class='table table-striped'>";
            echo "
                            <tr>
                                <td>" . $cont3 . "</td>
                                <td class='celda2'>" . $nfila->pelicula . "</td>
                                <td class='celda2'>" . $nfila->anio . "</td>
                                <td class='celda2'><button type='button' class='infoCompleta btn btn-default' data-toggle='modal'data-target='.modal" . $i . "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right'></span> Info Completa</button></td><td class='celda2'><button type='button' class='eliminarFav1 btn btn-danger'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign'>                                                     </span> Favoritos</button></td>
                            </tr>";
            $consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM `peliculas` WHERE titulo='$nfila->pelicula'";
            $resultado2 = $conexion->query($consulta2);
            if ($resultado2)
                {
                echo "
                            <div class='modal fade bs-example-modal-lg modal" . $i . "' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myLargeModalLabel'>
                            <div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
                            <div class='modal-content'>
                            <div class='modal-header'>
                            <button tyle='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                            <h4 class='modal-tigle'>" . $nfila->titulo . "</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class='modal-body'>
                            <center><a target='_blank' href='imagenes/" . $nfila->imagen . "'>
                            <img class='img-top-peliculas' src='imagenes/" . $nfila->imagen . "' class='img-rounded '></a>
                            </center><br />
                            <p><strong>Titulo Original: </strong>" . $nfila->tituloOriginal . "</p>
                            <p><strong>Año: </strong>" . $nfila->anio . "</p>
                            <p><strong>Duracion: </strong>" . $nfila->duracion . " min.</p>
                            <p><strong>País: </strong>" . $nfila->pais . "</p>
                            <p><strong>Director: </strong>" . $nfila->director . "</p>
                            <p><strong>Reparto: </strong>" . $nfila->reparto . "</p>
                            <p><strong>Género: </strong>" . $nfila->genero . "</p>
                            <p><strong>Sinopsis: </strong>" . $nfila->sinopsis . "</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class='modal-footer'>
                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Cerrar</button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>";
                }

            echo "<input name='usuario' type='hidden' value='$usuario'>";
            echo "<input name='titulo' type='hidden' value='$nfila->pelicula'>";
            echo "<input name='anio' type='hidden' value='$nfila->anio'>";
            echo "<input name='categoria' type='hidden' value='categoria' class='cat'>";
            echo "</table></form>";
            $cont3++;
            }

        echo "<span class='datos'></span>";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Hubo un problema al cargar las peliculas";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not fetching the results from `$resultado2 = $conexion->query($consulta2);`.  You are still using the last `$nfila`  from the earlier `$nfila = $resultado->fetch_object()`.  I'm going to assume you want something like:

```
   if ($resultado2) {
        $nfila2 = $resultado2->fetch_object();
```

Then use `$nfila2` in that inner conditional where you `echo` out the other portion.

```
  echo "
        ... stuff ....

      <h4 class='modal-tigle'>" . $nfila2->titulo . "</h4>

       ... more stuff....";
```

Also, I don't recommend nested queries on the same connection.  I'd do a fetch all on the original set:

```
 $results =  $resultado->fetch_all();
 foreach($results as $nfila) {
       //Do stufff
```

However, `fetch_all` only return arrays in mysqli, not objects so, just make sure you convert the `$nfila->pelicula` referneces to `$nfila['pelicula']`

Comment: Thank you very much it works, i would like to ask another question. Someone said me: "
This will have a repercussion on the performance of the application because the loop is executed n queries, depending on the server configuration can throw him, perhaps better put another way to do this". It's a good way to do this? Or should I do otherwise?

Comment: Yep, I'd do this in a single  joined query since you use the `$nfila->pelicula` as the key into the 2nd table.   Also you can run into doing 2 active queries on the same connection like that, so I'd at least do a fetch_all() on the first query result and iterate the array that provides.

Comment: Ok, but do you think there is a problem as i do?

Comment: I'd avoid nested queries.  See the update at the bottom of my answer

Comment: Ok thank you very much the answer was very help full.